# C++: set method parameter to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I have a class with a public member `int* classPointer`. I want to have a function `getPointer(int** externalPointer)`, that makes externalPointer point to the data of classPointer for me to use it outside of the class context.

I tried
`void getPointer(int** externalPointer) {externalPointer = &internalPointer;}`

and calling it like this: `getPointer(&externalPointer)`. I get the warning: "parameter externalPointer set but never used".

I don't think this is the correct way of doing it. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What's `internalpointer`?

Comment: If your pointer is public, why do you need a function at all?

Comment: You probably wanted `*externalPointer = internalPointer;`, but I can't be certain, it's hard to tell why you have this function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a double-pointer as a weird C-style way of emulating a reference to emulate a return value, then you'd want to write through the pointer to whatever it pointed at, not modify the local function argument:

```
void getPointer(int** externalPointer) {*externalPointer = internalPointer;}
                                        ^ add *            ^ lose &
```

Unless your goal is to baffle users of the function, use a reference when you want a reference:

```
void getPointer(int*& externalPointer) {externalPointer = internalPointer;}
```

and, if the purpose of the reference is to return a value, then just return a value:

```
int *getPointer() {return internalPointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in an (int**) and assign it its address, the thing that it points to will be classPointer.

```
class Blah
{
public:
  void getPointer(int** externalPointer)
  {
    *externalPointer = classPointer; // Add the star at the beginning.
  }

  int* classPointer;
}
```

Call is like this:

```
int* k = new int;
std::cout << "k=" << *k << " at address:" << k << std::endl;
blah.getPointer(&k);
std::cout << "blah.classPointer=" << *blah.classPointer 
          << " at address:" << blah.classPointer 
          << std::endl;
```

If the classPointer is public, you also don't need a method to do this.

```
Blah blah;
int* ptr = blah.classPointer;
```

Comment: Your function modifies a local variable, which is immediately destroyed.